# Nodejs child process-spawn in a container-docker

Tags: node.js, docker, child-process, spawn

I'm dockerizing a Node.js HTTP adaptive streaming web application. In the Nodejs server, I use the child process (spawn) to call FFMPEG to encode the user-uploaded file into different bit rates, then I later call MP4Box to dash the bitrates.

```
spawn('MP4Box', argDash, {cwd: './uploads'});
spawn('ffmpeg', arrStr, {cwd: './uploads'});
```

How can I call the two programs when running the nodejs server inside a container?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem running multiple processes within a docker container.  The container has it's own process namespace (ps in the container will show only processes created in that container, ps on the host will show all processes, including those that are inside the container).  Docker Engine daemon will only "monitor" PID 0 which is your ENTRYPOINT/CMD process, which I assume will be the parent process that spawned MP4Box and ffmpeg.

I am not familiar with these applications, but I would think you probably want to use a volume for ./uploads to bypass the union filesystem.